# How to extract a set of string before a sequence of numbers in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently looking for a query to extract a set of string. For example I have:

```
No |    DATA          |
1  |  AAABBB_123      |
2  |  BBCCC_AAA_444   |
3  |  AAA_BBB_CCC_567 |
```

And I wanted to have a select query that shows:

```
No |    DATA         |
1  |    AAABBB       |
2  |    BBCCC_AAA    |
3  |    AAA_BBB_CCC  |
```

How can I do that? Sorry I'm new to Postgres. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you want everything before the first `_`? What if you have `ABC_123_DEF_456`?

Comment: sorry, I've editted the question to be more precise

Comment: And what about `ABC_123_DEF_456`?

Comment: the data format is actually generated from a backend, it will always be [a set of string]_ then Number

Answer (score 0):

To remove unwanted characters, you can adapt:

```
select regexp_replace(data,'(_(\d+))', '') from mytable;
```

Comment: sorry, I've editted the question to be more precise